# Почему при отправке формы, перезагружается страница

Tags: ajax, javascript, post

Все работает нормально, но при отправке перезагружается страница, в чем может быть причина ?
И как её устранить ??

```
$(dialogForm).submit(function(){

        var message = $(dialogMessage).val();
        $(dialogSender).attr({ disabled:true, value:"Отправляю..." });
        $(dialogSender).blur();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/dialogSender.php",
            beforeSend: function(){
                if($(dialogMessage).val())
                   return true;
                else
                   alert("Пожалуйста, напишите сообщение");
                   return false;
            },
            data: {
               user_id: userID,
               dialog_id: dialogID,
               message: message
            },
            success: function(response){
                $(dialogSender).attr({ disabled:false, value:"Отправить" });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому-что ваш return false возвращается не из обработчика события submit.

сделайте.

```
$(dialogForm).submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   /*
      ваш код
   */
  });
```

вообще, асинхронные вызовы можно понимать как, например setTimeout:

вот например что выдаст вот этот код ?

```
function test() {
    setTimeout(function() {
       return "hello";
    },10);
    return "goodbye";
}

console.log(test());
```

Comment: А как тогда форму после отправки очистить?

Comment: форму очистить в хэндлере success.

Comment: test()->goodbye вернуло :)

Comment: @rnddev понимаете почему ?

Comment: так содержимое  beforeSend: просто в теле функции напишите.


ладно другой пример

    function test() {
     (function() {
        return 1;
     })()
     return 2;
    }
    test();

это почти то-же самое что:

    function a() {
       return 1;
    }

    function test() {
      a();
      return 2;
    }

понятно почему a вернется ?

Comment: @eicto все понял. спасибо. как удалить содержимое формы после отправки ? $(dialogMessage).remove(); убирает саму форму :(

Comment: `$(dialogMessage).val("")` ?